# Proc sql VALIDATE with CREATE TABLE

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am working in SAS EG and I have code like this:

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE new as
SELECT f1,f2
FROM work.orig
WHERE f1<>'x'
;
```

This works.

However, when I add a VALIDATE option, like below, I get an error:
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: (, SELECT.

ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE new as
VALIDATE
SELECT f1,f2
FROM work.orig
WHERE f1<>'x'
;
```

How do I use the validate option in proc sql?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you cannot use the `VALIDATE` with the `CREATE` statement.

Validate the underlying `SELECT`

```
proc sql;
VALIDATE
SELECT f1,f2
FROM work.orig
WHERE f1<>'x'
;
quit;
```

If that is successful, then your `CREATE` statement will work.

Comment: Dom is correct. You can not CREATE and VALIDATE in the same statement.